# How to export files generated to Azure DevOps from Azure Databricks after a job terminates?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

We are using Azure DevOps to submit a Training Job to Databricks. The training job uses a notebook to train a Machine Learning Model. We are using `databricks` CLI to submit the job from ADO.

In the notebook, in of the steps, we create a `.pkl` file, we want to download this to the build agent and publish it as an artifact in Azure DevOps. How do we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how that file is stored:

1. If it just saved on the DBFS, you can use `databrics fs cp 'dbfs:/....' local-path`
2. if file is stored on the local file system, then copy it to DBFS (for example, by using `dbutils.fs.cp`), and then use the previous item
3. if the model is tracked by MLflow, then you can either explicitly export model to DBFS via [MLflow API](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tracking.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.download_artifacts) (or [REST API](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#get-download-uri-for-modelversion-artifacts)) (you can do it to DevOps directly as well, just need to have correct credentials, etc.) or use [this tool to export models/experiments/runs to local disk](https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-export-import)